# Reading contents of a gzip file from a AWS S3 in R

Tags: r, amazon-s3

i'm trying to read my gziped csv file from S3

Given that I have a list of my data already like

```
> MyKeys
[1] "2020/07/25/21/0001_part_00.gz" "2020/07/25/22/0000_part_00.gz" "2020/07/25/22/0001_part_00.gz" "2020/07/25/23/0000_part_00.gz" "2020/07/25/23/0001_part_00.gz"
```

using

```
x<-get_object(MyKeys[1], bucket = bucket)
```

it returns

```
str(x)
 raw [1:42017043] 1f 8b 08 00 ...
```

i tryied to use

```
rawToChar(x)
gunzip(x, remove=FALSE)
read.table(rawConnection(get_object(MyKeys[1], bucket = bucket)))
read_delim(gzfile(get_object(touse[1], bucket = bucket)), ",", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
```

and a few more tricks that i dont remember.

and none of this worked.. i'm lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, after all I managed to find a solution.

```
df <- get_object(key, bucket = bucket) %>%
        rawConnection %>% 
        gzcon %>% 
        read_delim( "|", escape_double = FALSE,  trim_ws = TRUE, col_names = FALSE)
```

explaining a bit for anyone who finds himself in this kind of trouble

the method Get_object is the main S3 method. With rawConnection you can stream the gzcon which is the way to read and descompress a Gzip File (some sort of bitstream I dont know why it is this way...)
finaly  read_delim which is  no mistery for anyone.
and it is legen... wait for it...
there is a trick here!
when using RawConnection R allocates internally a vector for your file. and it STAYS there until you close it. usually you create one object and then close it like

```
x<- rawConnection(<args>)
close(x)
```

but in this case its created on the fly using magrittr's '%>%'  so i dont have the reference.
if you are doing the same as I am, and you are reading  months of data in thousands of files in a loop you will recive the error message

***All the connections are in use***

worry not.. Rawconnection store 128  files...tops..
so if you store into a local file or variable and  use the "garbage collector method"  closeAllConnections() and it wipes all stored files as rawconnections

Comment: Have you come up with a way to close the connection within the pipe chain? I am trying to use your method within map, but I quickly run into **All connections are in use**. This is the way I am calling it `df %>% mutate(foo = map(path, ~ get_object(object = .,
bucket = bucket) %>% rawConnection %>% gzcon %>% readLines(warn = F)))` Any ideas?

Comment: This works and doesn't have a bunch of assignments to throwaway variables `df %>% mutate(foo = future_map(path, ~ get_object(object = ., bucket = bucket) %>% rawConnection %>% gzcon %>% (function(con) {on.exit(close(con)); readLines(con, warn = F)})))`